# Excel macro is running on Workbook_Save without VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have inherited an Excel workbook with a fair amount of VBA in a single module, "Module1".

- There is no Workbook_BeforeSave or Workbook_AfterSave event in Module1
- There is no VBA code at all in the ThisWorkbook object or any other module
- There is nothing listed under Developer > Macros
- There are no add-ins
- There are no data connections

However, when I save the workbook, it is triggering code to run out of Module1. Where would the workbook be set up to do that if not in the VBA?

In the name manager, I discovered named ranges with references in the format `='Workbook name.xlsm'!Function1('Sheet1'!A1:A10)`, and their scope is `ThisWorkbook`. Since auto-calculate is on, I suppose this is why Function1 is getting called when the workbook (and by extension, range `Sheet1!A1:A10`) gets saved? However, all the named ranges refer to Function1 and the VBA in Function1 does not explicitly call any other function, so I'm still not sure how it can be that the other functions in Module1 are running when I save the workbook. The first line in Function1 is `Application.Volatile`, if that makes a difference.

Comment: There *can't* be a `Workbook_Anything` in `Module1`, `Workbook_EventName` would be in `ThisWorkbook`, or in a class module with a `Private WithEvents Workbook As workbook` field; standard modules can't handle events.

Comment: If the project doesn't have any class modules, any worksheet's code-behind module could act as one and declare a `WithEvents` workbook object and handles that object's `BeforeSave` event by invoking a method in Module1. Wouldn't be standard, but then, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: One way that might help you find what's happening: put a break in the code you know runs, then trigger it by saving the WB.  In the VBA IDE, look at the Call Stack (access via Ctrl-L) to see whats calling the Module1 code.

Comment: Are there any volatile UDFs in the workbook?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, thanks very much for your suggestions and sorry for my delay. I was trying out what you said. There is nothing in ThisWorkbook and there are no WithEvents declarations in other modules. However, when I inserted break points and then tried to step out, I ended up with the message box "Calculation is incomplete. Recalculate before saving?". This led me to discover some additional information which I am now going to put in my edited question.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thank you very much for the suggestion. I did put a break in a function CalcSourcePoints and look at the call stack, but there was nothing in the stack except CalcSourcePoints, and none of the other functions in the project call CalcSourcePoints. So it is still a mystery to me how it is getting called.